# Does Django 1.10 still need South to manage migrations?

Tags: django, database-migration, django-south

I am following [online instructions](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/18/starting-a-django-16-project-the-right-way/) on starting a Django project the right way.

The instructions are based on an earlier version of Django. From my (admittedly limited) knowledge of Django. The latest release of Django (1.10 at the time of posing this question), already handles migrations seemingly well - by way of the `manage.py` script.

My question then is this: Do I still need to install [South](https://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to manage my migrations, or can I simply skip that part of the instructions, and use `manage.py` to deal with my db schema changes?

Comment: You should use more up-to-date instructions. There are plenty to be found.

Comment: @DanielRoseman care tho share a link?. The resource I was using was the only one that came up (first page of Google) using the keywords django + virtuenvwrapper + pip + third party applications.

Comment: As usual with Django, you probably want to start with the official documentation and only fill in with other things as needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, South was for Django before 1.7. With 1.10 everything you would have used it for is baked into Django itself.